# Redirecting to homepage does not work after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xmlhttprequest

I have a form and its' submit button has a function attached to it.

```
    <form class="form">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="submitItem()">Save</button>
    </form>
```

My `submitItem()` function looks like this:

```
function submitItem() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/items';

    const data = {
      // input values here
    };

    const json = JSON.stringify(data);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.send(json);

    window.location.replace('/index.html');
}
```

The post request works - new item gets added, but the `window.location.replace('/index.html')` does not work and leaves me in the form page with submitted data in the URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Since your button element is inside a form tag, whenever the button is clicked, the form will trigger a submit event since the button type is "submit". 
Hence, the page refreshes. This will override your window.location.replace("/index.html") and thus nothing happens.

One solution is, **remove the enclosing form tags**.

Or include an **onsubmit="submitItem(); return false"** to the *form tag* as shown below.

> Don't forget to remove the *onclick* on the button.

```
 <form class="form" onsubmit="submitItem(); return false">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```